# How to properly use DI with Quartz.NET IScheduler?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1, quartz.net

I'm working on an Asp.Net Core 3.1 application in which I need to schedule different type of jobs. We're using Scoped jobs in order to work with Scoped services (like the dbcontext). As of recent, Quartz.NET supports scoped jobs out of the box, with the help of the `UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionScopedJobFactory` (as described in the official documentation).

However, I'm not sure **how to register the actual scheduler** in order to inject this in my services and being able to schedule new jobs at runtime.

I know I can get hold on a IScheduler by doing this:

```
ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
     scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
```

But I haven't found any documentation on how to register this in my actual Services pipeline. **What is the proper/recommended/documented way of doing this?**

Comment: The hosting extension has registration and start/stop https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/hosted-services-integration.html . See the example ASP.NET Core app in the GitHub repository

Comment: You ever figure this out? Running into the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

[Docs](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/microsoft-di-integration.html#installation) describes how you should use `Quartz.NET` with DI container. So it's better to check described examples first.

Regarding dynamic resolving of `ISchedulerFactory` with scoped services, the factory registered in the container once you call:

```
serviceCollection.AddQuartz(q => 
{
   ...
   // your configuration
   ...
   q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionScopedJobFactory()
   ...
})
```

So in your service you can inject `ISchedulerFactory` and perform actions on it.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, because I want the scheduler to start automatically together with the rest of the application. I have a custom made SchedulerService which is meant to be implemented in other services to schedule jobs at runtime. But if my SchedulerService inject the SchedulerFactory, gets a new Scheduler and starts it, won't there potentially be a ton of parallel started schedulers running?

Comment: Could you add example of usage so my answer will be more concreate? `SchedulerFactory.Get` does not create a new scheduler it will return default registered scheduler (more here you can get your scheduler instance by passed id)